# How can I install Arial fonts to my Office within Wine?

Tags: wine, fonts, microsoft-office, playonlinux

I installed MS Office 2007 using PlayOnLinux, and the Arial font is italic, for some reason. Any hint on how to install it correctly?

This two approaches I found in the internet have failed:

- To copy the fonts from my Windows "Fonts" folder to `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/` and execute `fc-cache`.
- To delete all "Arial" in the folders: `~/.PlayOnLinux/fonts` and `~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Office2007/drive_c/windows/Fonts/`

--update:

follows the screenshot of my Arial:

[image]

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts` not work?

Comment: @arochester not.. Arial is still showing to me as a strange italic font..

Comment: Is it actually Italic, or is it some other font being substituted? The most likely candidate is the Arial replacement font from the ttf-liberation package.  Do you have that installed?

Comment: @Scott Ritchie: Yes, I have the ttf-liberation installed. I think it's not really Arial italic, look my screenshot.

Comment: Tom - just to clarify - you have click "install, other - Microsoft Fonts" in PlayOnLinux and added the Fonts to your MS Office package?

Comment: @fossfreedom no, I have copied the fonts from my Windows system, and execute `fc-cache` after that. (it was a hint from a colleague)

Comment: @fossfreedom sorry?

Comment: ... I meant - try adding the fonts via PlayOnLinux.

Comment: @fossfreedom it worked! =D (please, add as an answer)

Comment: excellent news - have added an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PlayOnLinux provides a mechanism to install and modify "bottles" of wine-software.

One of these is the install Microsoft Fonts to a "bottle" - the picture below will give an idea of what to do.  Note - I dont have MS Office, but the principle still applies.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Select any Microsoft Office package (e.g Microsoft Office)
2. In the right sidebar click `Configure`
3. In the `Install Components` tab select "Microsoft Core Fonts" and click install

[image]